# Smash Up - Treasure Card Question

Tags: smash-up

Treasure Card pictured.

If used as a special as noted.  A base is scoring off.  Can someone use this card to move a minion TO that base?   They currently do NOT have a minion on the base about to be scored but want to use the special on this card to move TO the scoring base.[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, the card is used to move minions *from* a base, not *to* a base.

If you use it as a special, then you must chose the base that is scoring. And, per the action text, you move a minion *from* the base, so the target must move the minion away from the scoring base.